# Can I read a gigantic text file with Parallel Computing?

Tags: matlab, file-io, parallel-processing, large-files

I have multiple text files that are about 2GB in size (approximately 70 million lines). I also have a quad-core machine and access to the Parallel Computing toolbox.

Typically you might open a file and read lines as so:

```
f = fopen('file.txt');
l = fgets(f);
while ~ isempty(l)
    % do something with l
    l = fgets(f);
end
```

I wanted to distribute the "do something with `l`" across my 4 cores, but that of course requires the use of a `parfor` loop. That would require that I "slurp" the 2GB file (to borrow a Perl term) into MATLAB a priori, instead of processing on the fly. I don't actually need `l`, just the result of the processing.

Is there a way to read lines out of a text file with parallel computing?

EDIT: It's worth mentioning that I can find the exact number of lines ahead of time (`!wc -l mygiantfile.txt`).

EDIT2: The structure of the file is as follows:

```
15 1180 62444 e0e0 049c f3ec 104
```

So 3 decimal numbers, 3 hex numbers, and 1 decimal number. Repeat this for 70 million lines.

Comment: perhaps you can [split](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2016894/97160) the file into 4 equal parts, and process them using `parfor`, one on each core... I'm thinking this is still IO bound, so you are not going to benefit much by spinning multiple process, unless the "do something with l" part is really CPU intensive. Perhaps even MATLAB is not the best tool for the job, lookup [tag:mapreduce]

Comment: If the file is a long binary vector, you can use `fscan` \ `fread` with `parfor` with giving the proper pointer. I'll try to show an example later...

Comment: @natan: here is an example with `fread` to read structured binary file in a vectorized manner: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8108683/97160

Comment: very nice.... you got my +1

Comment: For those interested, there was a recent article on Loren Shure's blog that shows how to perform big data analysis using [distributed arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/distributed.html) on a cluster of computers: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/11/11/in-memory-big-data-analysis-with-pct-and-mdcs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, I'm showing an example of [memory-mapped](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/memory-mapping.html) files using [`memmapfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memmapfile.html) class.

Since you didn't provide the exact format of the data file, I will create my own. The data I am creating is a table of `N` rows, each consisting of 4 columns:

- first is a `double` scalar value
- second is a `single` value
- third is a fixed-length string representing a `uint32` in HEX notation (e.g: `D091BB44`)
- fourth column is a `uint8` value

The code to generate the random data, and write it to binary file structured as described above:

```
% random data
N = 10;
data = [...
    num2cell(rand(N,1)), ...
    num2cell(rand(N,1,'single')), ...
    cellstr(dec2hex(randi(intmax('uint32'), [N,1]),8)), ...
    num2cell(randi([0 255], [N,1], 'uint8')) ...
];

% write to binary file
fid = fopen('file.bin', 'wb');
for i=1:N
    fwrite(fid, data{i,1}, 'double');
    fwrite(fid, data{i,2}, 'single');
    fwrite(fid, data{i,3}, 'char');
    fwrite(fid, data{i,4}, 'uint8');
end
fclose(fid);
```

Here is the resulting file viewed in a HEX editor:

[image: binary file viewed in a hex editor]

we can confirm the first record (note that my system uses [Little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) byte ordering):

```
>> num2hex(data{1,1})
ans =
3fd4d780d56f2ca6

>> num2hex(data{1,2})
ans =
3ddd473e

>> arrayfun(@dec2hex, double(data{1,3}), 'UniformOutput',false)
ans = 
    '46'    '35'    '36'    '32'    '37'    '35'    '32'    '46'

>> dec2hex(data{1,4})
ans =
C0
```

---

Next we open the file using memory-mapping:

```
m = memmapfile('file.bin', 'Offset',0, 'Repeat',Inf, 'Writable',false, ...
    'Format',{
        'double', [1 1], 'd';
        'single', [1 1], 's';
        'uint8' , [1 8], 'h';      % since it doesnt directly support char
        'uint8' , [1 1], 'i'});
```

Now we can [access the records](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/constructing-a-memmapfile-object.html#braidws-28) as an ordinary [structure array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/create-a-structure-array.html):

```
>> rec = m.Data;      % 10x1 struct array

>> rec(1)             % same as: data(1,:)
ans = 
    d: 0.3257
    s: 0.1080
    h: [70 53 54 50 55 53 50 70]
    i: 192

>> rec(4).d           % same as: data{4,1}
ans =
    0.5799

>> char(rec(10).h)    % same as: data{10,3}
ans =
2B2F493F
```

The benefit is that for large data files, is that you can restrict the mapping "viewing window" to a small subset of the records, and move this view along the file:

```
% read the records two at-a-time
numRec = 10;                       % total number of records
lenRec = 8*1 + 4*1 + 1*8 + 1*1;    % length of each record in bytes
numRecPerView = 2;                 % how many records in a viewing window

m.Repeat = numRecPerView;
for i=1:(numRec/numRecPerView)
    % move the window along the file
    m.Offset = (i-1) * numRecPerView*lenRec;

    % read the two records in this window:
    %for j=1:numRecPerView, m.Data(j), end
    m.Data(1)
    m.Data(2)
end
```

[image: access a portion of a file using memory-mapping]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I will have to adapt this for my needs but this is definitely a great start.

Comment: Just want to remind you that the above works for binary files with fixed-length fields and records (we know in advance how many bytes and the precision of each field). It wont work for space-delimited text files, not unless you use some kind of padding to get all fields aligned.

Comment: Right. I might go back to the source of this file and ask him to make it a binary format for me.

Answer (score 2):

Some matlab's built-in functions support multithreading - the list is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4PG4AN/). There is no need for the Parallel Computing toolbox.

If the "do something with l" can benefit from the toolbox, just implement the function before reading another line.

You may alternatively want to read the whole file using

```
fid = fopen('textfile.txt');
C  = textscan(fid,'%s','delimiter','\n');
fclose(fid);
```

and then compute the cells in C in parallel.

---

If the reading time is a key issue, you may also want to access parts of the data file within a `parfor` loop. Here is an example from [Edric M Ellis](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/307594#835402).

```
%Some data
x = rand(1000, 10);
fh = fopen( 'tmp.bin', 'wb' );
fwrite( fh, x, 'double' );
fclose( fh );

% Read the data
y = zeros(1000, 10);
parfor ii = 1:10
    fh = fopen( 'tmp.bin', 'rb' );
    % Get to the correct spot in the file:
    offset_bytes = (ii-1) * 1000 * 8; % 8 bytes/double
    fseek( fh, offset_bytes, 'bof' );
    % read a column
    y(:,ii) = fread( fh, 1000, 'double' );
    fclose( fh );
end

% Check
assert( isequal( x, y ) );
```

Comment: You are suggesting reading the whole file in memory? I dont see how that answers the question. File IO operations will never be multithreaded... And what happens when the file gets bigger than available RAM

Comment: @Amro that was my exact thought - I want to avoid "slurping" the entire file ahead of time.

Comment: The RAM issue could easily be solved by using `textscan` with a loop:

`for k=1:nTimes, C  = textscan(fid,'%s',nLines,'delimiter','\n'); end`

Since it will keep the current file position it won't slow the process.

Comment: @Werner: right, reading in chunks is definitely a viable solution. Another option is [`memmapfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/memory-mapping.html). My point is that all those are not easily parallelized, which is what the OP was asking about.

Comment: @Amro nice to hear about this `menmapfile`, didn't know about that solution x). Yeah, I noticed your concern with the parallelization but I can't answer that, hope Magla can enlighten that. I would say that it is pointless to parallelize since the reading speed will be limited to the disk read speed even if the file is separated at `n` different files. I think the best solution would have one thread reading while others are processing the already read information but it would be quite boring to synchronize.

Comment: @Amro you ought to write up an answer using `memmapfile`. This might be the best way to go.

Comment: @DangKhoa: it's not always applicable and depends on your file. Is it a structured file or a general ASCII text file?

Comment: @Amro It's ASCII, but it's always 7 space-delimited columns of either decimal (cols 1,2,7) or hex (3,4,5,6).

Comment: @DangKhoa: it would help if you post a small sample of the file showing the structure of its records. But if the file is space delimited rather than fixed-length fields, I doubt `memmapfile` would easily apply, at least without first converting the structure of the file to something conformant..

Comment: Nice example! @Amro is quite right that you will only see benefit from PARFOR if what you do with the data takes much longer than the time required to read it from disk.

Comment: @Amro see my edit. I'm trying to optimize the data processing right now.. that may be a follow-on question.

Comment: @DangKhoa: I posted an example using `memmapfile`. I started it before you made the recent edit, so you'll have to adapt the code to your data :)

Comment: @Magla: I added a link to the newsgroup thread with Edric's example